# How to check the record count from text file for different source and mail it is record is not equal to 0

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting, mailx

I have a select query which runs and generate the count. It exports the Answer in a text file which has below records eg.:

```
    Unprocessed record for A Sources
----------------------Unprocessed record count for ABC SOURCE ------------------
abc_count=            0
--------------------Unprocessed record count for CDE Source --------
CDE_count=            0
-----------------------Unprocessed record count for DEF Source -----------------
DEF_count=            0
------------------Unprocessed record count for GHI Source ----------------------
GHI_count=            56
```

I want to write a Unix command which checks if for above source any of the count is not equal to 0
if it is not equal to 0 then mail it to the required team.

Comment: *mail it to the required team* - what required team? what should be mailed, the whole record?

Comment: Required team means Users. 

if any of the record count is not equal to 0 then mail the whole record .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use the `grep` to get output of the wanted process
`awk` the second collumn and `test` if its zero
then `echo` the message you want to `mail` or `mailx` with the needed subject and adresses.
You could iterate over multiple predifine strings

Below answer used based on exactly the output as given in question and assume that furthe checks will have the same pattern output.

```
for CHECK in $(awk '{print $1}' output.txt | grep count=| cut -d"=" -f1)
do
if [ $(grep $CHECK output.txt | awk '{print $2}') -ne 0 ]
then  
echo "$(grep $CHECK output.txt")" | mailx -s "CHECK ABC PROCESS" foo@bar.com
fi
done
```

Comment: GiannakopoulosJ Thanks for replying....getting some syntax error though syntax error at line 9 : `"' unmatched

Comment: missed a ) at echo echo "$(grep $CHECK output.txt" | mailx -s "CHECK ABC PROCESS" foo@bar.com.   I have already added it.

Comment: I hope i am using the brackets correctly                                                  for CHECK in $(awk '{print $1}' hello | grep count=| cut -d"=" -f1)
do
if [ $(grep $CHECK output.txt | awk '{print $2}') -ne 0 ]
then  
echo "$(grep $CHECK output.txt)" | mailx -s "CHECK ABC PROCESS" foo@bar.com
fi
done
still getting below error :-----awk: can't open hello

Comment: as it is but change output.txt with your output file. error awk: can't open hello try to find a hello file. in your case i don't know the file. adjust the script in your output file needs.

Comment: GiannakopoulosJ Thank you so much for your help. It is working fine.

Comment: I have some negative reaords as well. what if i dont want records which are not eqaul to zero which was implemeted previously and also records which are negative.can i use -gt instead of -ne

Comment: @VinayakDas yes greater than zero will ensure always backlog

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk '/[[:digit:]]/ { if ($2 == 0) { system("echo \""$0"\" | mailx -s \"Check Count\" someone@someserver.com") } }' countfile
```

You can use awk and check for all lines with digits. Then use awk's system function to send emails.

DISCLAIMER - The risks associated with command injection need to be judged before implementing such a solution.